# Load Data MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a problem with the loading csv data into mysql table.

I have data like this:

```
Identity : name=Tomas, age=28, hoby=traveling;
Identity : name=Justin, age=29, hoby=Fhising;
```

I want results like this

```
|field1|field2|  field3 |
|tomas |  28  |traveling|
|justin|  29  | fhising |
```

Answer (score 1):

### Using **direct** LOAD DATA INFILE with set expression

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'FILENAME.CSV'
    INTO TABLE TABLENAME
    (@f1, @f2, @f3)
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    LINES TERMINATED BY ';'
    SET `field1` = SUBSTRING(@f1, LOCATE('name=', @f1)+5), `field2` = SUBSTRING(@f2, LOCATE('age=', @f2)+4), `field3` = SUBSTRING(@f3, LOCATE('hoby=', @f3)+5)
```

Note I haven't tested it. So there might be errors. Please tune it according to your need.

### Using `awk` as preprocessor

Preprocess your csv file with `awk` and invoke `LOAD DATA INFILE`

```
awk -F[,=\;] '{print $2","$4","$6}' < FILENAME.CSV > PROPER.CSV
```

Now in mysql,

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'PROPER.CSV'
        INTO TABLE TABLENAME
        FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
        LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

Comment: OK thanks for the help

now,, 
if me used

SET `field1` = SUBSTRING(@f1, LOCATE('name=', @f1)+5), `field2` = SUBSTRING(@f2, LOCATE('age=', @f2)+4), `field3` = SUBSTRING(@f3, LOCATE('hoby=', @f3)+5)

it's coment for the name and number of columns remain,
when this names and numbers column varied? what should i do,,,

Comment: I could not understand you. Would you give an example?

Comment: i want to delete before "=" with LOAD DATA, so only one step,, :)